# How can I use Tailwind in React to animate a div to fill out its length from left to right

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

[image]

This is an example of the divs, I just want to them to grow from left to right. Is this possible in Tailwind in React?

Comment: Yup, you can do that. Tailwind not providing any classes for this so you have to use logic to achieve this.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I could use logic to achieve this?

Comment: Please share your example then i will update it as per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this but it needs additional `css`
file

##### Example:

`animation.css`

```
@keyframes fill-left-to-right {
  from { width: 0; }
  to { width: 100%; }
}

.fill-left-to-right {
  animation: fill-left-to-right 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

`Component.js`

```
import './animation.css'
return (
  <div className="fill-left-to-right">
    {/* Your content here */}
  </div>
)
```

You can do this for every `div` specifying different class and changing the `width` prop of that custom class